# Inject script with ScriptInjector

Tags: gwt

What is the exact `ScriptInjector` code for this HTML script tag:

```
<script>navigator.id || document.write('<script src="https://login.persona.org/include.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: The script tag is on the html in our server and the script source is on Mozilla Persona servers

Comment: I would seem that the example is [in the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html). As far as your `navigator.id` check goes - you'll have to write that logic yourself. Further - this question reads like "gimme the code" - with almost 6K rep, you should know better.

Comment: Yes you're right. My question sound like that, what I wanted was the most straightforward way to do this with GWT, say using GwtQuery :-)

Comment: So what's wrong with the code from the javadoc? Could you maybe be missing a call to `setWindow(TOP_WINDOW)`?